# Convert a python string so it can be used as the same name of a dictionary

Tags: python

I have 7 python dictionaries each named after the format `songn`, for example `song1`, `song2`, etc. Each dictionary includes the following information about a song: `name`, `duration`, `artist`. I created a list of songs, called `playlist full` of the form `[song1, song2, song3...,song7]`.

Here is my code:

```py
song1 = {"name": "Wake Me Up", "duration": 3.5, "artist": "Wham"}
song2 = {"name": "I Want Your...", "duration": 4.3, "artist": "Wham"}
song3 = {"name": "Thriller", "duration": 3.8, "artist": "MJ"}
song4 = {"name": "Monster", "duration": 3.5, "artist": "Rhianna and Eminem"}
song5 = {"name": "Poison", "duration": 5.0, "artist": "Bel Biv Devoe"}
song6 = {"name": "Classic", "duration": 2.5, "artist": "MKTO"}
song7 = {"name": "Edge of Seventeen", "duration": 5.3, "artist": "Stevie Nicks"}

playlist_full = []
for i in range(1, 8):
    song_i = "song"+str(i)
    playlist_full.append(song_i)
```

Now I am trying to use an item in the `playlist_full` list to in turn get the name of the song in the corresponding dictionary. For example, to see the name of `song3`, I would like to run:

```py
playlist_full[2].get("name")
```

The problem is that while `playlist[2]` is `song3`, python recognizes it only as a *string*, and I need python to realize that that string is also the name of a dictionary. What code will allow me to use that string name as the name of the corresponding dictionary?

Edit:

Based on the answer by @rob-g, the following additional lines of code produced the dictionary of songs that I wanted, as well as the method of accessing the name of `song3`:

```py
playlist_full = [eval(song) for song in playlist]
print(playlist_full[2]["name"]
```

Comment: Why are you using the original variables? Just put the songs directly into the list: `playlist_full = [{...}, {...}, ...]`

Comment: Or you can do `playlist_full = [song1, song2, song3, ...]`

Comment: ANY TIME you find yourself with variables called `xxx1`, `xxx2`, `xxx3`, etc., you need to replace those variables with a list (or sometimes a dictionary).   Your loop then becomes unnecessary.

Comment: I'm trying to do this programmatically. I imagine a scenario where there are thousands or millions of songs. No one would want to construct a list by hand.

Comment: eval("song3") returns the value of song3, as does eval("song" + str(3)).

Comment: wouldn't be more like a sql problem than created "database" using python variables?

Comment: For future readers of this thread, `eval` is never the right answer. If you find yourself reaching for it to solve these kinds of problems, it’s an indication you need to step back and rethink your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [eval()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_eval.asp) like:

```py
eval(playlist_full[2]).get("name")
```

which would do exactly what you want, evaluate the string as python code.

It's not great practice though. It would be better/safer to store the songs themselves in a dictionary or list that can have non-eval'd references.

Comment: Thank you, Rob. This works! I am quite new to python, so I'm just playing around with dictionary comprehensions at the moment, experimenting.

Comment: Based on your answer, I was able to construct the dictionary that I wanted, using a dictionary comprehension, and then access the name of song2 directly:

`playlist_full = [eval(song) for song in playlist]`
`print(playlist_full[2]["name"])`

Answer (score 1):

```
varnames=locals()
playlist_full = []
for i in range(1, 8):
    song_i = "song"+str(i)
    playlist_full.append(varnames[song_i])
    
print(playlist_full[2].get("name"))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's completely redundant to keep your data as both individual variables and members of a list.  If a list is what you need, create it that way in the first place.

```
playlist_full = [{"name": "Wake Me Up", "duration": 3.5, "artist": "Wham"},
    {"name": "I Want Your...", "duration": 4.3, "artist": "Wham"},
    {"name": "Thriller", "duration": 3.8, "artist": "MJ"},
    {"name": "Monster", "duration": 3.5, "artist": "Rhianna and Eminem"},
    {"name": "Poison", "duration": 5.0, "artist": "Bel Biv Devoe"},
    {"name": "Classic", "duration": 2.5, "artist": "MKTO"},
    {"name": "Edge of Seventeen", "duration": 5.3, "artist": "Stevie Nicks"}]
```

Comment: Doing that is fine if there are just 7 songs. I wanted a method that would take thousands or millions of such song dictionaries and programatically turn them into a list of dictionaries or a dictionary of dictionaries.

Comment: @JoshG so you intend to have a program with millions of individual variables?  That's clearly unworkable.  You need to have a different approach, which was the point of my answer.  Perhaps I was a little too subtle in making the point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) built-in function to do that:

```py
for i in range(1, 8):
    song_i = "song"+str(i)
    playlist_full.append(locals()[f'song{i}'])
```

Comment: This looked promising but did not produce a dictionary of dictionaries. If you run your code, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @JoshG you didn't ask for a dictionary of dictionaries, you asked for a *list* of dictionaries.  I believe that's what this produces.

Comment: @MarkRansom did you run your code? The first entries are `song1`, `song2`, etc. The later entries are dictionaries.

Comment: @JoshG then I suggest you double-check what your local variables `song1` and `song2` are.